# Why is "and" not used before ", etc."?

Tags: differences, adverbs, conjunctions

When you use **, [etc.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/et-cetera)** to indicate that further, similar items are included, for example:

> We’re trying to resolve problems of withdrawal, peer pressure, **etc.**

Is it incorrect to use **, and etc.**?

Comment: *etc.* is short for *et cetera* which means "and other things* in Latin.  So the *and* in *and etc.* is redundant.

Comment: "Et cetera" is generally considered to transliterate as "and so forth".

Comment: wow, good answer if that is really all it is

Comment: The Department of Redundancy Department recommends reading http://www.fun-with-words.com/redundant_acronyms.html :-) (In reality, they're at most half-redundant, unless you are a very strict prescriptivist.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Deadrat and Hotlicks mentioned in the comment, in Latin, "[et](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=latin%20english%20dictionary)" is a conjunction which means "and" and "cetera" is an adverb which means "others" or "the rest".

Therefore, if you write "and et cetera (etc.)", you are writing "**and and** others" which is not correct. That's why you should not use "and" before "etc."